# How to get the other fields values by the id in Javascript or RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the database, I have a table called `Questions`. It has `four columns` like

```
Id, Question_text, Question_type, Answer_table
```

The user can select only the `id` and `question_text`. I am able to get the `Id` and `question_text` value. I need to get the value of `Question_type` and `Answer_table` from that `Id`.

For example,

If the user selects the `question_text = 'City'` with `Id = 5`.

I want the values for other columns of `question_type` and `Answer_table` by the `params` of this `id`. to store in a separate variable.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying here, may be rephrasing your question will give you better response

Comment: @Ross . I changed the question. Please have a look and help me. Thanks for your support

Comment: Can you not just do Question.find(id) to get the question object. 
I have edited the question, but I am still not sure what you meant by the last line of the question

Comment: I need to get the values for that other columns by the params of this id.

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: Actually I am getting the value of id in javascript and store in the seperate variable. I need to get the same way of other column value and store in the seperate variable.

Comment: Please remove the downvote. Do not discourage me. I am a newbie.

Comment: Please remove the downvote... I am unable to post new questions. I am fresher student. Please encourage me!!!! Please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using the Map method in ruby on rails to get the values of other columns by through association. Thanks!!